# I need to fix Bootstrap h-100 class it is not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I have a sidebar in admin panel. And I try to make this sidebar height of 100%, but I could not solve my problem this way.

https://jsfiddle.net/irankhosravi/u96nykbx/1/

```
<html class="h-100">
<head>
    <title>Admin</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
<body class="h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col-md-2 h-100 bg-success" id="sidebar"></div>
    <div class="col-md-10 bg-danger" style="height: 500px;"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all, you shouldn't place `.row`s as direct children of `<body>`. You need to wrap them in either `.container` or `.container-fluid`. If you do not, you'll experience a horizontal scrollbar on your page at various screen widths.
Please note you should not have a `.container` inside another `.container`, but you can have a `.container` inside a `.container-fluid`.

Secondly, in order for `.h-100` to work you need to pass it down the chain of children to each element, because it's always `100%` of its parent. If one parent doesn't have it, the chain is broken and it's children will have `100%` of `0` (or `maxContent` if that element has some flow content).

Here's your example with `.container`:

```html
<html class="h-100">
<head>
    <title>Admin</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body class="h-100">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-md-2 h-100 bg-success" id="sidebar"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10 bg-danger h-100"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here it is with `.container-fluid`:

```html
<html class="h-100">
<head>
    <title>Admin</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body class="h-100">
  <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-md-2 h-100 bg-success" id="sidebar"></div>
      <div class="col-md-10 bg-danger h-100"></div>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

While considered fairly easy to pick up and use, Bootstrap has a few *gotcha*s. Until you get them, read [the docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/) carefully and rely on their examples.

Answer (score 1):

You should mention:

h-25 , h-50 , h-75 and h-100 set your div's height based on your parent's height. You have 2 ways :

1. Set the height of your parent's division
2. Use `height = 100 vh` in your css file fir your division